# confused about logical meaning of direction of a space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors, machine-learning, clustering

Here are the description about how PCA (Principal component analysis) is calculated (referred from this [book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387310738)). Confused about this statement -- "We can define the direction of this space using a D-dimensional vector `u1`", I think a vector can represent a direction and length, how could it represent a space? And when talking about PCA, it is projection into a space or projection into a vector (i.e. dot product)?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If $u_1$ is any vector not orthogonal to the line, then we may decree that the projection of $u_1$ onto the line yields the positive direction. So any non-orthogonal vector yields an orientation of the line.

Comment: Thanks Alex, vote up for your reply. For "to the line", do you mean `x`, which PCA project from?

Comment: @LinMa "The line" refers to the one-dimensional subspace you're projecting onto.

Comment: Thanks for reply Alex, vote up. It seems you mean line and subspace are (representing) the same thing, but my confusion is line is line, space is space (space is composed of infinite number of lines), how could a line represent a subspace? And when you say sub-space, do you mean two dimensional or could be any dimension?

Comment: @LinMa I'm talking about a vector subspace. A vector space of dimension 1 is precisely a line.

Comment: Thanks Alex, vote up. I am a bit confused about statement, "the projection onto a **one-dimensional** space (M = 1). We can define the direction of this space using a **D-dimensional** vector u1", I **highlight** where I am confused, and I think one dimension and D (D>1) dimension are quite different, how could D dimensional vector represent one dimension? I think one dimension line is like `y=x`, `y=ax+b`, `y=1` (where `x` and `y` are both scalar value other than a vector)? Maybe I am not using the right terminology here?

Comment: The equation $y=ax + b$ represents an *affine* line, but only a line in the vector space sense if $b = 0$. "$D$-dimensional vector" just means that $u_1$ is an element of $D$-dimensional Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^D$. As a concrete example, take the $2$-dimensional vector $u_1 = (1,1)$ and the line $y = 0$. Then the projection of $u_1$ onto the line yields the standard orientation on the line, i.e. it goes from left to right.

Comment: Thanks Alex, you mentioned "vector space of dimension 1 is precisely a line", want to confirm my understanding is correct, (1) when we say vector of dimension 1, it is vector of 1 dimension and it is a scalar value, but when we say (2) vector **space** of dimension 1, it is a n-dimensional vector which is a line, correct? (tricky part of the description is, whether `dimension 1` is for **vector**, or `dimension 1` is for **space**), correct understanding (this is the whole part of my confusion in the beginning)?